# Cannot assign a value of type '(UInt32)' to a value of type 'String?'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm fairly new to iOS programming and I'm trying to randomize between two numbers in Xcode using Swift and I get this error:

> Cannot assign a value of type `(UInt32)` to a value of type `String`

When I use the `print` method, it works fine but when I assign a label to print out the result it gives me that error.

Code:

```
let lower : UInt32 = 10
let upper : UInt32 = 19
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower
lblNum.text = (randomNumber)
```

Comment: lblNum.text = "\\(randomNumber)"

Comment: This is one of those situations where the real answer should be: complete an introductory tutorial on Swift or read a book...

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
lblNum.text = "\(randomNumber)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`UILabel` property `text` is of type `String?`. You're trying to assign `UInt32` value, which is not going to work. As you wrote, the error message is:

> Cannot assign a value of '(UInt32)' to a value of type 'String?'.

You have to convert `UInt32` to `String` and then assign. Several possibilities ...

```
lblNum.text = "\(randomNumber)"
```

... or ...

```
lblNum.text = String(randomNumber)
```